# C# NPOI library and invalid zip compression

Tags: c#, excel, npoi, sharpziplib

I'm using the NPOI library to read and write XLSX spreadsheets in a C# application. This library seems to work, I could open, write and re-open an Excel file.

I found a problem when I tried to open a NPOI file with MS Excel, its say that the file has some corrupted content. However NPOI library can open its file. I could understand that this is a compression issue, seems that the zip compression of xlsx is not valid for Excel and this issue is caused by ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll, for this reason a copy of this dll is distribuited with the NPOI library.

I tried to add this dll in my project references, but the compression still doesn't work.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DotNetCore.NPOI with version 1.2.0 (it`s works for me).

Answer (score 0):

I recommmend you use official NPOI release: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/